# What's a better way to implement centralized logging for desktop application in Azure?

Tags: azure, logging

I have built WPF and Electron desktop applications where I'm currently logging custom usage and error logs. They are sent to an Azure Function which in turn talks to an Azure MSSQL database with a stored procedure to add log messages.

I feel this is not a very optimal solution. The function sometimes takes a long time to spin up, and the database potentially feels a bit overkill for logging (maybe it's OK). And I don't know if it's safe to add the link to the logging function in my applications even though it's very restrictive in what it accepts. You need to send the logs in a specific structure with some mandatory fields. But this feels more like "security by obscurity".

Isn't there a better way to implement a centralized logging service for my different applications? I want to be able to add more applications in the future as well (all will send the same structured logs). Are there any features in Azure to handle custom logging?

Comment: I think first of all you need to choose if you want asynchronous or synchronous logging. If you can live with asynchronous it would be better to save the log locally and upload to some API that receives it and puts it in to your DB. If you need to have synchronous then you should be thinking of handling it parallel/async in your application so its not blocking your application from running.

Comment: The logging implemented in my applications are asynchronous "fire and forget". And if something goes wrong the logs are written to disc and retried at a later point.

Comment: Maybe use [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview)? I've written [a blogpost](https://dev.to/expecho/monitoring-non-web-apps-using-azure-application-insights-part-2-basic-instrumentation-2fcj) on how to use it in desktop apps.